# extract last week data (and not last 7 days)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

I have data with below format.

```
id     - autoincrement
myDate - timestamp
```

What I want to extract is get ids of for the last week.

**Note** By last week, I meant from Sat - Thu and not last 7 days. Considering current date (12-Feb-2013), for me, last week would be `2-Feb-2013 to 8-Feb-2013`.

***I know you would say, week starts from Sunday, but as I am working in Arab countries, here Friday is OFF and work starts from Saturday.***

I know for last 7 days it would be just below code

`BETWEEN NOW() and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`

### [Data at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fda4a/1)

Comment: The condition would be opposite; lower value comes first for the `BETWEEN` syntax. ;)

Comment: `where week(myDate) = week(now()-1) and year(myDate) = year(now())` for normal weeks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656996/week-of-the-year-for-weeks-starting-with-saturday   duplicate of this?

Comment: @DoSparKot : World week start with Sunday and my week start with saturday

Comment: and this [MySQL - Saturday as first day of Week?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687119/is-it-possible-to-set-mysql-to-have-a-saturday-as-the-start-of-the-week)

Comment: Can't you use PHP for this?

Comment: @SalmanA : I can do this in Java, but I wanted to do this in MySQL as I would be using same query for my mobile application where I am using PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try below method to compute the desired result:

```
SELECT *,WEEKOFYEAR(dt),DAYOFWEEK(dt),DAYNAME(dt), DAYOFWEEK(NOW()),WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) 
FROM tab1 
WHERE 1
AND 
(
  (DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = 1 OR DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = 6 OR DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = 7) 
  AND 
  WEEKOFYEAR(dt) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) AND DAYOFWEEK(dt) < 6
)
OR 
(    
  (DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = 2 OR DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = 3 OR DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = 4  
  OR DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = 5)
  AND
  (
     (
      (WEEKOFYEAR(dt) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())-2 AND DAYOFWEEK(dt) >= 6)
      OR 
      (WEEKOFYEAR(dt) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())-1 AND DAYOFWEEK(dt) > 1 AND DAYOFWEEK(dt) < 6)
     )
  )
);
```

I know this is not the smartest way, but based on this you might get hint for better solution.

### [Demo at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40e9b/5)

Comment: with your query I am getting data from monday to saturday. I want it from saturday to friday. :(

Comment: @FahimParkar Yes I was working on while SqlFiddle went down, I have updated the SQL and it went down again, however it is close, it shall get you started though, please see I have hard-coded date to check the various scenario, but you can test that once done, replace hard-coded '2013-02-10' with NOW() function

Comment: can you have sqlfiddle solution with `NOW()`?

Comment: @FahimParkar It is there with NOW() option but You are expected to change yourself to test :)